# Using .config in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Beginner here
Having trouble getting a label to update on a simple countdown app,
Can anyone explain why the label does not update in the loop?

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x100')

seconds_inp = tk.Entry(root)
global time_label
time_label = tk.Label(root, text = '00', font = 20)
start_button = tk.Button(root, text = 'start', command = lambda: countdown_clock(int(seconds_inp.get())))
def countdown_clock(seconds):
    while True:
        seconds = seconds - 1
        time.sleep(1)
        time_label.config(text = seconds)


        print(seconds)
        if seconds == 0:
            time_label.config(text = 'time!')
            break



time_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
start_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
seconds_inp.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The UI cant update since you are stuck in the loop using `time.sleep`. Look at `.after(...)`

Comment: The `time.sleep()` is interfering with tkinter's `mainloop()`. You should be able to get the `Label` to update by using the universal [`update_idletasks()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method (after the call to `config()`). An alternative would be to use the universal `after()` widget method in place of `time.sleep()` because it doesn't interfere.

Comment: Now when you have a working answer below by Michael, just as a side not, It is never recommended to use while loops in GUIs (especially if you're starting out), 'cause it often blocks the GUI from updating cause it doesn't  reach the `mainloop`. In those cases use `update_idletasks()` as suggested by @martineau. 

Even in your own code, just adding `time_label.update_idletasks()` after the `time_label.config(text=seconds)` line solves the issue in GUI update.

But as michael said, beware of things like subtracting a second even before the timer has started, and grid arrangement.

Comment: @PSSolanki however, using `update_idletaks()` will eventually lead to window not responding, even though the time runs, the GUI fails to keep up with the pace and also i noticed that, it leads to over-writing of the labels too(i dont know why, though)

Comment: Umm i don't know why that is happening to you, It works perfectly fine on my machine. And I can definitely say it's not because of system performance or resources, 'cause I just have a notebook. As far as the overriding labels is concerned, i (and michael too ) addressed to it because  OP's code has grid arrangements in a different way (i'm unsure of exact reason tbh), but make changes to the code on your own and then using update_idletasks works just fine

Comment: @PSSolanki hmmmm, ive noticed that `update()` works better than `update_idletasks()` for me, would appreciate if the OP would mark an answer, to close the Q

Answer (score 1):

Use `after` instead of `while` and `wait`. Also, you were subtracting a second as soon as your clock begins. Send the subtracted value to the next call instead. If all you are going to do is stick every widget on the next `row` in one `column` then you don't have to be specific in `grid()`, you just have to make sure you call `grid` on the widgets in the proper order. If you add more columns the rules change back to how you were doing it.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x100')

def countdown_clock(s, t):
    if not s:
        t.configure(text='time!')
        return
    
    t.configure(text=s)
    root.after(1000, countdown_clock, s-1, t)
    


time_lbl     = tk.Label(root, text='00', font=20)
time_lbl.grid()

start_btn    = tk.Button(root, text='start', command=lambda: countdown_clock(int(seconds_ent.get()), time_lbl))
start_btn.grid()

seconds_ent  = tk.Entry(root)
seconds_ent.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` loops, leads to windows being unresponsive after sometime, so the best way is to get rid of that and use the inbuilt, `after()` method.

Here is a working example:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('150x100')

seconds_inp = tk.Entry(root)

time_label = tk.Label(root, text='00', font=20)
start_button = tk.Button(
    root, text='start', command=lambda: countdown_clock(int(seconds_inp.get())))


def countdown_clock(seconds):
    seconds = seconds - 1
    time_label.config(text=seconds)
    call = root.after(1000, countdown_clock, seconds)
    if seconds == 0:
        root.after_cancel(call)
        time_label.config(text='Time up!!')
    print(seconds)


time_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
start_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
seconds_inp.grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

All i did was,I removed the `while` because it will interrupt the `mainloop()` method, so then i used `after()` method to call the function continuously till `second` reaches 0, and then i cancel the `after()` and finally update the label. And i removed `global` outside the functions as those are pointless to be called outside functions.

Hope this cleared your doubt.

Cheers