# Why is my Python Tkinter GUI running slow and becomes unresponsive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

From what I have understood by reading other stackoverflow topics on similar issue, my GUI is lagging due to Python being single threaded. Apparently, I am running two while loops in my code, however, I am unable to identify the reason why it is happen in my code specifically. I know there is a for loop in the function I have and the window.mainloop() at the end.

When I run my code the numbers are properly represented in the GUI, however, the window itself becomes laggy when dragging it around or pressing on the START button again. All of this end up breaking the GUI and makes it go "not responding". Any advice on how to fix my code so I can show live data in my GUI and have it work without lags?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import statistics

dataList = []

def function():
    for i in range(10):

        dataList.append(i)

        time.sleep(1)

        currentLabel.configure(text="CURRENT")
        currentValue.configure(text=i)

        minLabel.configure(text="MIN")
        minValue.configure(text=min(dataList))

        maxLabel.configure(text="MAX")
        maxValue.configure(text=max(dataList))

        avgLabel.configure(text="AVG")
        avgValue.configure(text=round(statistics.mean(dataList)))

        window.update()

window = Tk()
window.title("Data Count")
window.geometry('800x750')
window.title("v1.0")

startBtn = Button(window, text="START", bg='#0388fc', fg='#ffffff', command=function)
startBtn.configure(font=("Ariel", 16))
startBtn.grid(column=1, row=5, pady=(25, 0))

currentLabel = Label(window)
currentLabel.grid(column=1, row=13)
currentValue = Label(window)
currentValue.grid(column=1, row=14)

avgLabel = Label(window)
avgLabel.grid(column=1, row=11)
avgValue = Label(window)
avgValue.grid(column=1, row=12)

minLabel = Label(window)
minLabel.grid(column=1, row=7)
minValue = Label(window)
minValue.grid(column=1, row=8)

maxLabel = Label(window)
maxLabel.grid(column=1, row=9)
maxValue = Label(window)
maxValue.grid(column=1, row=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not positive, but I think that sleep(1) might be putting the tkinter mainloop to sleep. Would certainly cause lag. To delay functionality there is a method called `after` or something like that which will have the tkinter mainloop launch a callback for you after a certain number of milliseconds has past. Think you may want to use that instead.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire is right. `time.sleep()` is never recommended in `GUIs` (neither are `while` or `for` loops). Instead try to use (A) `global methods` like `.after(..)` or `.update_idletasks()` on the widget instead of sleep functionality because `time.sleep()` interferes with the `GUI mainloop`. (B) try using `recursive functions` instead of `loops`.

Read more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63779131/10145519) to see why exactly it matters in a similar question (it has 2 answers).

Comment: You can also use Threading to increase your application speed